# Bad dpi on Nexus 7

Tags: android, dpi, nexus-7

I have incorrect UI on Nexus 7.

I have 10" tablet with mdpi, and my UI is OK. But on 7" nexus 7 all images and texts look very big.

I coped images from mdpi to tvdpi. and now, it is OK for me.

But, is it correct to have 2 folders with the same images? How to resolve these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this properly. You will require different images for different pixel densities.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> But, is it correct to have 2 folders with the same images?

You could do that but images won't look sharp because you are using MDPI images for XHDPI devices. You should understand after reading the guide.